# What happens when Linux goes out of letters for drives?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, udev, devices

Let’s say I have 50 USB flash drives.

I assume they get to be `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdz`. What comes after `/dev/sdz`?

Comment: Extension of the same question - what happens with virtual xvd devices like `/dev/xvda` ? NVME devices of the format `/dev/nvme1n1` or with partiiton `nvme2n1p3`   Does the old format IDE driver giving `/dev/hda` device nodes have the same limits ?

Comment: Amusingly, I once tried to help a Windows user who *had* run out of drive letters. This was years ago. He had two floppies, several compressed drives (each uses two drive letters), external drives and several CD-ROMs and DVDs. Drive A: to drive Z: is all you get.

Comment: @Wastrel At that point you start mounting additional volumes under directories. Yes, that is a very *nix-like approach. Works fine. The underlying physical device paths are numerical, so it'll happily keep incrementing forever (`\Device\HardDisk1`, etc.).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It will go to `/dev/sdaa`, `/dev/sdab`, `/dev/sdac`, etc.

Here is a comment from the source code:

```
/**
 *  sd_format_disk_name - format disk name
 *  @prefix: name prefix - ie. "sd" for SCSI disks
 *  @index: index of the disk to format name for
 *  @buf: output buffer
 *  @buflen: length of the output buffer
 *
 *  SCSI disk names starts at sda.  The 26th device is sdz and the
 *  27th is sdaa.  The last one for two lettered suffix is sdzz
 *  which is followed by sdaaa.
 *
 *  This is basically 26 base counting with one extra 'nil' entry
 *  at the beginning from the second digit on and can be
 *  determined using similar method as 26 base conversion with the
 *  index shifted -1 after each digit is computed.
 *
 *  CONTEXT:
 *  Don't care.
 *
 *  RETURNS:
 *  0 on success, -errno on failure.
 */
```

[https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/scsi/sd.c#L3303-L3324](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f2689a7662809ff39f2b24e452d11569c21ea2f/drivers/scsi/sd.c#L3303-L3324)

Comment: I wonder how many SCSI devices one would need to attach to reach [`/dev/sdeignfully`](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/sdeignfully)?

Comment: @Tom Given that it's a British English word perhaps it originated from [The Grauniad](http://grauniad.co.uk)?

Comment: @Tom you'd have to connect 2061986601 devices (https://tenderleo.gitbooks.io/leetcode-solutions-/content/GoogleEasy/171.html)

Comment: @Tom why sdeignfully?

Comment: @user253751, one presumes because that's the first English word beginning `sd` that contains "full" within it.

Comment: @user253751 Longest word in my en-US wordlist (~275k entries) that begins with "sd".

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sdeignfully says   "Obsolete word for `distainfully` "

Comment: ... provided the `int buflen` is big enough

Comment: The comment is not so long. It would be better to quote it, in case that link breaks. Though nothing wrong with keeping the link, of course.